# google analytics - multiple trackers on one page (cookie conflict)

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, widget

I'm writing a web application that's supposed to be embedded in other people's websites (kind of a widget). I'm using Google Analytics to track all the people that visit all instances of my script on the embedding websites. The problem is that I don't know how to use it so that it doesn't interfere with those websites' own Google Analytics accounts. I'm storing the tracker variable in a namespace, so I thought that should do it, but I haven't realized that GA stores its settings in cookies (__utma, __utmz etc.), and those cookies are used by both trackers, if there are two of them on the same page... So for example if I use _setVar to store some kind of user-defined variable in Google Analytics, and the embedding site does the same, we overwrite each other's values...

Of course it would be easiest if Google provided a way to change the name of the cookies to a custom one, but I can't find any way to do it. I thought about using cookie domain or path to force a separate cookie, but this doesn't work, because if I set domain or path to something other than the real domain/path, then the cookie is not readable for the page after reload...

Does anyone know a way to have two trackers on one page and make them use separate cookies so that they don't overwrite each other's settings?

Or, if that's completely impossible - is there any other analytics service with similar functionality as GA in which this is possible? (it would have to have advanced features like event and campaign tracking...)

Comment: Why should you have access to visitor data from sites that do not belong to you? How is your component being embedded?

Comment: Because I want to know how the widget is being used. It's really more an embedded website than a widget, "widget" suggests something small and not complicated...

It's embedded by inserting <script...> into the website, then the widget's GUI is created dynamically in Javascript, it downloads various data using AJAX (JSONP), and it should track user's actions inside the widget using Google Analytics.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Now made easy with the new asynchronous tracking code. :)

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#MultipleCommands

Comment: Updated link: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html#MultipleCommands

Comment: Not so easy, in simple situations it works but you should becareful: see the links in Torok's post - Google doesn't recommend multiple analytics account on the same page: https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsCookies?hl=nl-NL = If you have multiple accounts tracking the same web property (e.g. page or sets of pages), both accounts will read from and set the same set of cookies. This set up is generally not recommended.

Answer (score 18):

You can install multiple instances of the Google Analytics tracking code on your web pages to send data to multiple properties in your account.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en

Or you can get creative and do the following per Google's instructions. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#multipletrackers

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto', {'name': 'newTracker'});
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('newTracker.send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

Don't have to use different cookie names as Google Analytics happily works with multiple trackers on the same page. See answers for question *[Google Analytics - Multiple Trackers for Several Accounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264630/google-analytics-multiple-trackers-for-several-accounts)*.

*Update*

It turns out that using [multiple trackers is a working method but has some pitfalls](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2009/02/26/pitfalls-tracking-multiple-accounts-ga/). One of those, that is, you cannot apply different user segmentation for each of them. John Henson demonstrates a workaround that [coerces GA to use different cookies](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2009/03/06/cookies-tracking-multiple-accounts-ga/), may be you should check it.

Comment: I'm not so sure. If both of the trackers call _setVar to set a custom tracking variable, it seems that only the variable from the second tracker can be found in the cookies, and the one from the first tracker is getting lost. Unless I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: @Psionides: and it seems that's true--so far I always used the same settings for different trackers. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone still has this issue and wants an easy paste, my issue was using my own google tracking for my code that was being added to other people's pages that might also be using google tracking. I have tested this and confirm it works as expected:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];

_gaq.push(['some_unique_name._setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
_gaq.push(['some_unique_name._trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

I am using also using events

```
_gaq.push(['some_unique_name._trackEvent', 'Event Category', 'Event Action', 'Event Label']);
```

If anyone sees an issue with it, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks arlomedia. It took awhile to figure out since this page and many other are quite convoluted with solutions.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2009/03/06/cookies-tracking-multiple-accounts-ga/) listed by Török, it seems the correct answer is to use [_setCookiePath](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCookiePath). This causes each tracker to use completely different cookies.

Example code from website:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker(”UA-11111-1″);

    pageTracker._setDomainName(’domain.com’);

    pageTracker._setCookiePath(’/subdirectory/’);
    pageTracker._trackPageview();

    var otherTracker = _gat._getTracker(”UA-22222-1″);
    otherTracker._setDomainName(’domain.com’);
    otherTracker._trackPageview();
</script>
```

When you link from one domain to another, every link that posts to the other domain has to look like this:

```
<a href="pageTracker._linkByPost('otherdomain.com/petStoreCart/legalTerms.php');"
```

This will add Google Analytics specific query string values that will be used by the above script to set the cookie ([source](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html)).

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work across domains - I can't set a cookie for a different domain that is displayed in the location bar. So if my widget is embedded at e.g. http://website.com, and the script is loaded from http://widget.com, then I can only set cookies for http://website.com (and so does the embedding website itself) - and we still have a conflict.

Comment: Added more info for cross domain linking.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Google recommends against this practice:

> Installing multiple instances of the Google Analytics Tracking code on a single web page is not a supported implementation. We suggest that you remove all but one instance, and make sure that you have the code from the correct profile installed on every page that you would like to track.

https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1032400

Answer (score 1):

I have used this structure on our site and clients sites and it works like a charm...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");    
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js'     type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")); 
</script> <script type="text/javascript"> 

try {

//Original tracking
var pageTracker_ORIG = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXXX-1");
pageTracker_ORIG._setDomainName('.sleepinggiantmedia.co.uk');
pageTracker_ORIG._trackPageview();

//New Analytics tag
var pageTracker_SGM = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXXX-1");
pageTracker_SGM._setDomainName('.sleepinggiantmedia.co.uk');
pageTracker_SGM._trackPageview();


} catch(err) {}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var otherTracker = _gat._getTracker(”UA-22222-1″);
otherTracker._setDomainName(’domain.com’);
otherTracker._trackPageview();
```

Answer (score -3):

[This person](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=4731d8a407382376&hl=en) is having the same problem on the Google Analytics help fourm. I'd suggest taking a look at the thread. But regularly GA doesn't support multiple trackers.

I like [Clicky](http://getclicky.com) myself, but it costs money.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but it looks like the suggested solution is to either download the GA script and hack it, or hack its internal variables from outside - both of which sound dangerous and unstable...