# Google Analytics - async tracking with two accounts

Tags: google-analytics, statistics

I'm currently testing GAs new async code snippet using two different tracking codes on the same page;

```
_gaq.push(
    ['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1'],
    ['_trackPageview'],
    ['b._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2'],
    ['b._trackPageview'] 
);
```

Although both codes work, I've noticed that they present inconsistent results. Now, we aren't talking huge differences here, only 1 or 2 visits / day every now and then. However, this site is *tiny* and 1 or 2 visits equates to a 15% difference in figures. Now, the final site has much more traffic, but my concerns are;

- will this inconsistancy scale with traffic?
- assuming not, is a slight variation in recorded stats an accepted norm?

Comment: This question must have an updated answer, since Google Analytics has a way of using multiple tracking codes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239042/google-analytics-multiple-trackers-on-one-page-cookie-conflict

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can avoid the conflicting cookies by setting a different domain for google analytics.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-NNNN-1']);

// primary profile
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'www.domain.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(function() {
    // create the second async tracker
    _gaq._createAsyncTracker('UA-NNNN-2', 'blogTracker');
});

// secondary profile (this is the default domain setup if not specified) 
_gaq.push(['blogTracker._setDomainName', 'domain.com']);
_gaq.push(['blogTracker._trackPageview']);  
//]]>
</script>
```

This will keep the cookies separate.

Note: I am using this setup to track events in a second profile to keep my bounce rate numbers accurate. The second profile tracking code is only used on my blog, thus, is not a complete profile on purpose.

Comment: I'll make an adsense analytics integration question to know if I can use this code above. I know Google can’t track multiples accounts, at least not YET! But should generating new profiles inside ONE previous account be the ONLY SOLUTION? What if I have 100 websites? 3 YEars has passed, google staffs did not realize a method? I would borrow to insert a 3rd code inside each side, but letting accounts BE, creating new ones inside each profile and letting it’s history aside THEM generating new CODES… Are we in 1911 or 2011? I'm thinking using this code to track my account both account so...

Comment: ...the previous one and new one I'll create inside profile that's been already integrated with google adsense... make sense doesnt?

Answer (score 2):

Are they from different accounts ?

If so check follow statement from GA website

> Multiple Analytics Accounts on a Given
>   Page Some users want to track the same
>   page or set of pages in multiple
>   Analytics Accounts. Analytics is
>   designed to work effectively with a
>   single account-to-web-property
>   relationship. If you have multiple
>   accounts tracking the same web
>   property (e.g. page or sets of pages),
>   both accounts will read from and set
>   the same set of cookies. This set up
>   is generally not recommended.

Comment: That doesn't really answer either of my questions at all, and I think is only relevant to the old tracking code... I should point out that the js I'm using comes from Google's own code examples; http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html#MultipleCommands

Comment: Well the problem that I had with two accounts was that the visit count between them was different. If the codes are from the same account, then you dont have the same problem as I had

Comment: Ivo is right.  Using multiple trackers (in sync or async) will result in one tracker overwriting the cookie values of the other.  How badly this skews your data is entirely dependent on how you use those trackers.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider with tracking in multiple accounts is that any events in the page will be sent to whichever account was set last in the _setAccount call. I spent months wondering why my events weren't showing up under my main account and then realized we had an extra set of tracking code appearing after the main tracking code with a call to _setAccount for the affiliate account. My event tracking code appeared to be working fine, but events never showed up in my account. Moving the affiliate code to before our main tracking code solved the problem.