# Three Google Analytics Codes on One Site?

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-analytics, web

I was wondering if it was possible to have two or more sets of Google Analytics tracking codes on one page. There's going to be a single webpage that is accessible through either normal methods (desktop or mobile browser), or accessed through scanning the QR code on the product packaging and being redirected that way.

The client wants three things tracked:

1. Analytics for the full page (all methods of connection)
2. Analytics for just those connected via normal methods
3. Analytics for those connected via QR code

I have already developed a means of differentiating the connection method, and switching the Google provided Javascript for 2 and 3.

So is this possible, to have two analytics codes on one page? I have checked all over, can't find an answer that is to the point.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239042/google-analytics-multiple-trackers-on-one-page-cookie-conflict

Answer (score 0):

A single analytics will report browser and OS used and the origin of traffic. Hence, there's no reason to use three cookies, three JS files when you can just generate a personalized report with the data you need

Answer (score 0):

Don't use different trackers for this, use [custom variables](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html). Splitting it up loses you valuable insight into how different use cases navigate the site.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is ever looking for this:

http://www.publicinsite.com/qr-codes-google-analytics-track-mobile-devices/

That;s the best bet I think