# Two google analytics accounts per page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [google analytics - multiple trackers on one page (cookie conflict)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239042/google-analytics-multiple-trackers-on-one-page-cookie-conflict)

I've searched around the internet about this question, but cant find the answer I am looking for.

I've developed a blog, with some special features. Each user get their own subdomain when they register.

Everything is free, but with ads. And I currently use google analytics to track the total number of visitors and pageviews.

I've developed a small counter so that each user can se how many visitors and pageviews they have, but for more detailed informatino they need to use their own "google analytics", or what ever they want to use.

So. The code I use now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx1-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'sub.domain.com']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
```

I dont know what type of analytics service each user will use, I let them insert their own code within the HEAD.
So, IF they use google analytics, will our two accounts at google analytics get the correct number of visitors? The code will then be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx1-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'sub.domain.com']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx2-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'sub.domain.com']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
```

Or do I have to do it like:

```
_gaq.push(
    ['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1'],
    ['_trackPageview'],
    ['b._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2'],
    ['b._trackPageview'] 
);
```

Where both trackers are within the same . ??

Thanks!

Comment: The latter method is one of the methods which I've known to work as I'm using on one the sites.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example and it works. I have the same code on mine.

```
_gaq.push(
  ['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-1'],
  ['_trackPageview'],
  ['b._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-2'],
  ['b._trackPageview']
);
```