# profile page with users own analytic code to track the visitors

Tags: php, javascript

We will ask uses to save Google analytic code which is look like `UA-519****`
This Google analytic code we will use in users profile to track traffic.

So User can see his profile traffic in his own Google analytic.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-51*****']); // Users Analytic token to track traffic 
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-3****']);// system Analytic token to track traffic 
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

To achieve this task , above code i have tried. But seems not working. Is there is another way to perform this task ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239042/google-analytics-multiple-trackers-on-one-page-cookie-conflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/?hl=pl#MultipleCommands) page.

It appears to be able to handle multiple tracking accounts. Try the following

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-3*****']); // System Analytic token to track traffic 
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

_gaq.push(['b._setAccount', 'UA-51****']); // Users Analytic token to track traffic 
_gaq.push(['b._trackPageview']);

_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);

// Rest of Code
```